# NumPy - Vectorizing loops involving range iterators

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Is there any way to make this work without for loops?

```
import import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

L = 1
N = 255
dh = 2*L/N
dh2 = dh*dh

phi_0 = 1
c = int(N/2)
r_0 = L/2

arr = np.empty((N, N))

for i in range(N):

    for j in range(N):

            arr[i, j] = phi_0 if (i - c)**2 + (j - c)**2 < r_0**2/dh2 else 0


plt.imshow(arr)
```

I've tried calling function(x[None,:], y[:, None]), where:

```
function(i, j):

    return phi_0 if (i - c)**2 + (j - c)**2 < r_0**2/dh2 else 0
```

but it requires list .any or .all methods. I'm looking for specifically functionless method (without fromfunction and vectorization).
Big thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this without loops? Keep in mind even list comprehensions utilize the "for" syntax.

Comment: @msaba92 Because loops are slow in python. There is a vectorized approach in many cases, which uses "internal" loops writtten in C and/or optimized by LAPACK, BLAS, SVML or others.

Comment: You can overcome the speed issue by computing the for loop just in time. You can use `numba` package to `jit` your function and for loop. It handles numpy well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Vectorized solution using open grids

We could use two *open* range/grid arrays for `N` simulating the same behavior as the iterators -

```
I = np.arange(N)
mask = (I[:,None] - c)**2 + (I - c)**2 < r_0**2/dh2
out = np.where(mask,phi_0,0)
```

**For a generic range on the two loops**

For the generic case where we would iterate through two loops that extend till say `M` and `N` respectively, we could make use of [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) to create those open grids and then use on the same lines -

```
I,J = np.ogrid[:M,:N]
mask = (I - c)**2 + (J - c)**2 < r_0**2/dh2
```

**For a generic number of loops**

For a generic number of loops, simply create as many variables as the number of loops. Hence, for three loops :

```
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        for k in range(P):
```

, we would have :

```
I,J,K = np.ogrid[:M,:N,:P]
```

, then use `I,J,K` instead of `i,j,k` respectively for element-wise operations like we have here.

---

**Alternative to replace last step for this specific case**

Last step could also be implemented with elementwise multiplication by scaling to `phi_0` with `mask` as the `else` part is setting to `0s` -

```
out = mask*phi_0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use numbers of row and column to calculation, a loop is necessary.
You can use one loop. Numpy has ndenumerate attribute that iterate over your matrix.

```
def function(i, j):
    return phi_0 if (i - c)**2 + (j - c)**2 < r_0**2/dh2 else 0

for (i,j), value in np.ndenumerate(arr):
    arr[i, j] = function(i, j)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your real goal is not to avoid loops, but to get good performance (in this case 670x speedup) a simple approach would be to use a compiler. In this example I use Numba but you can also use Cython, which is a bit more work to to (type declaration,...)

**Exampe**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

L = 1
N = 255
dh = 2*L/N
dh2 = dh*dh

phi_0 = 1
c = int(N/2)
r_0 = L/2

@nb.njit()
def create_arr(N,phi_0,c,r_0,dh2):
  arr = np.empty((N, N))
  for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
      if (i - c)**2 + (j - c)**2 < r_0**2/dh2:
        arr[i,j]=phi_0
      else:
        arr[i,j]=0.
  return arr

arr=create_arr(N,phi_0,c,r_0,dh2)
```

**Timings**

```
#Pure Python:   58 ms
#Numba version: 0.086 ms (the first call takes longer and isn't included in the timings)
```